# Parsing error to translate /_sql/translate use UPDATE

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-sql

I'm using the SQL translator on ElasticSearch on a query that had `UPDATE` keyword.
I can translate `SELECT` queries, but `UPDATE` is not working.

```
POST /_sql/translate
{
    "query": "UPDATE inspections SET business_state='RS' WHERE business_city='Passo Fundo'"
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "line 1:1: mismatched input 'UPDATE' expecting {'(', 'DEBUG', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SELECT', 'SHOW', 'SYS', 'WITH'}"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "line 1:1: mismatched input 'UPDATE' expecting {'(', 'DEBUG', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SELECT', 'SHOW', 'SYS', 'WITH'}",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "input_mismatch_exception",
      "reason": null
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update SQL Command is not supported.
[Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-commands.html) lists the SQL command which are supported